# How to expose a service in kubernetes running on Barematel

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Kubernetes Version: 1.10  Running on Barematel

No. of masters: 3

We are running our multiple microservices inside a Kubernetes cluster. Currently, we are exposing these services outside of the cluster using `NodePort`. Each microservice has it's own NodePort so we have to maintain a list with the corresponding microservices. Since we are running on Barematel we don't have features like LodeBalancer while exposing a microservice.

**Problem:** - Since we have multiple masters and workers inside the cluster we have to use a static IP or DNS for any master at a time. If I want to access any service from outside the cluster I have to use as - `IP_ADDRESS:NODEPORT` or `DNS:NODEPORT`. At a time I can use the address of any one master. If that master goes gown then I have to change microservices address with other master's address. I don't want to use a static IP or DNS of any master.

What could we a better way to expose these microservices without NodePort? Is there any feature like LoadBalancer over Baremetal? Can `INGRESS` or `Nginx` help us?

Answer (score 0):

There is a LoadBalancer for Baremetal, it's called [METALLB](https://metallb.universe.tf). Project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/metallb), unfortunately this solution is in alpha state and is more complex.

You can also [follow the instructions from NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/) and setup round-robin method for TCP or UDP.

`Ingress` only supports http(s) over ports 80, 443 only.
You can of course setup your own ingress controller but it will be a lot of extra work.

`NodePort` downside is a limited number of usable ports which is from 30000 to 32767, and if IP of the machine changes your services will be inaccessible.